# Type definition does not seem to work in react-hook-form 7

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I defined the types of my form fields. I have have 3 different fields, with 3 different types. After initiating the form each field seems to be valuable with all 3 different types. What is wrong?

[image]

[Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-get-started-ts-forked-pnneo)

```
type Inputs = {
  val1: string
  val2: number
  val3: boolean
};
```

mouseover types shows:

```
const val1: string | number | boolean
```

Comment: Is this sandbox examle reflecting your cde which shown in the question? I am getting a whole different one

Comment: @NimnaPerera what do you get? Did you go to the sandbox link?

Comment: Are now it seems okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@vuvu This behaviour has been fixed in version `7.0.6` of `react-hook-form` and types are now properly retrieved. (see [this PR](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/pull/4721) for reference)

Comment: In the sandbox the error goes away, but in my project, though using 7.3.4 it still show "string | boolean | number". Do you have any ide why?

Comment: When there are more than 9 fields the error still occurs. Do you know why? I  created a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-get-started-ts-forked-zmz4b

Comment: The [TS type definition](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/65520033b2e838dc0f42921c28efa00f956dcf54/src/types/form.ts#L165) of `watch` using an array of keys is define for a maximum of 10 keys.

If you need to watch more than 10 keys, two options that I see as of now, first simply make two calls to the watch function with the additional keys.

Otherwise you'll need to specify the array to the watch function (aka: `watch<['key1, ...]>(['key1, ...])`) not very pretty imo and mistakes can easily happened.

Comment: @vuvu Just to let you know, the workaround that I presented in the above comment will soon be unnecessary as [this PR](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/pull/5005) has been merged, effectively removing the "10 keys" limitation. :)

Answer (score 1):

@vuvu Your code is working perfectly. The behavior you got is happening because of watch is returning a array. Inside a array if you placed items with different types then you can have items with those all types inside the array. You can read this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/typescript-array) as an additional reading material.

As it says,

> Of course, you can always initialize an array like shown below, but you will not get the advantage of TypeScript's type system.
>
> `let arr = [1, 3, 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', true, false];`

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I will have to ask react-hook-form-team why they changed from object to array losing all the advantage of typescript.